# Email links result in 404

Tags: support, jobs, email

I got a reminder email regarding an SO Careers message. On clicking the links within the email (to either reply or change my settings), they all go to 404 pages.

The links in question:

Edit preferences: `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/213178#objectives`

View message: `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/366797/messages/1139654`

Is it some setting on my end which I have changed? My profile was recently private but updating it to public didn't seem to fix this.

I have also replied to the message with the buttons within the message to show I am not interested but this is the second email I have received about this message. Do I need to take further action?

NB: I am logged in when I get the 404's

[image]

EDIT:

I was informed by the support team that the accounts are already linked. However, I keep getting these emails. The message the email mentions does exist and I have already replied to it. The links show the user ID 366797 but mine is 436375

Comment: Please check the actual URL in the address bar when you get the 404? Is it the same as you posted?

Comment: It is, I copied it from the address bar directly

Comment: Are you logged in? Do you see your name in the top bar? (in Careers)

Comment: I removed the slugs from the URL's in the question. I am logged in when this happens

Comment: Starting a bounty does not notify those who answered. You should post a comment on the answer, letting the dev know that it's still not working. (I just did that)

Answer (score 6):

The email you received is for a different account than the one you are logged into. Your logged in account cannot access those links.

We can merge the accounts if you'd like; contact `careers@stackoverflow.com` and we'll get right on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sent off an email to merge the accounts.

Comment: Looks like case is still not solved, i.e. accounts still not merged, based on the bounty OP started.

Comment: Hmm, this looks familiar... The careers and SO accounts are linked, but perhaps there's another account out there somewhere.

Comment: @Adam you mean another Careers account? Do you have access to those, or do only Careers devs have?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do, after a fashion. I'll look tomorrow and see what's what.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is due to the fact that you might be using the wrong account. After the merge, the userID was deleted but did not replace your current account, which is normal. The link assumes that nothing has changed so only the deleted account can see it so you get 404 when attempting to view the links. The links will only show to the user with the ID listed, but say it is not yours. Thus you cannot see the links provided in the e-mail and apparently settings don't transfer... This is also why I can't see the message either and why Dean Ward attempted to merge the accounts.

TLDR; the cause is that the links would only show to the user with the ID 366797, regardless of any merging of any type. To help with viewing the links, try using the "contact us" link at the bottom and contact SE for help. When they realize the original target profile has been merged, they will probably send you new links that you can view or something.

Comment: So how do I get the accounts in to a state where they are linked properly and I don't receive emails for an account that no longer exists?